# DocuSign Embedded signing. A user who can choose a Sign tab position for all signatories in envelope

Tags: c#, docusignapi, signing

I'm trying to implement a built-in signature in C #. I successfully implement the case when I don't define the signer cards and when I call CreateRecipientView in EnvelopesApi at that point the signer can choose the position of the Signer tab, and that's great.

My question is whether I can create an envelope in DocuSign for 2 embedded signatories and 1 (call that user administrator or anything else) that can open the document to sign and use the DocSign user interface to select the position of the signer tabs for both signatories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that, but you have to keep the envelope in "draft" mode when you let your administrator user use what we call "Embedded Sending" and redirect them to the "tagger" page where they can put the tags for the other two users.
They would be the one sending the envelope once they finished placing these tags for the other two users.
Here is a code example for this - https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/embedded-sending/